# MediaPlayer does not play mp3 in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to play an mp3 file from a website. The following code gives me no errors but it doesn't play the mp3.

Android version is 2.2 and I'm testing it on my HTC Magic.

**Edit:** it works when I run it on a virtual device v. 2.2. If you know why it doesn't work on my HTC Magic, I would very much like to know.

Fix'd :)

Comment: Dumb question but it has to be done: are you sure your URL to the mp3 is valid/exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media volume was 0 on my phone, which explains why it only works on the virtual device. I fixed this by adding this line to the onCreate method:

```
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```